# smartgit: executing a command has failed: trunk is outdated

Tags: git, svn, error-handling, smartgit

How can I solve this problem?

I use smartgit/hg for an svn repository and it always worked, with only one trunk. Now, that I started another branch in it, and used "Cherry-pic" I have this problem:

```
Executing a command has failed.
svn: Verzeichnis "/trunk" ist veraltet
```

which means: "Folder /trunk is outdated" or such

How can I solve this?

That message is coming everytime again

This is my tree:
[image]

it the bottom screen, the log looks like this:

```
Synchronize: svn: Verzeichnis »/trunk« ist veraltet
HEAD is now at 347425d Merge remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/svn/trunk' into trunk
HEAD is now at 347425d Merge remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/svn/trunk' into trunk
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Already up-to-date!
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Already up-to-date!
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Trying simple merge with d800a237bf659f59bfa63781afcede0a8a31e148
Trying simple merge with cecb0300061476beaf44b82ef3aebceb753ecb0a
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Already up-to-date!
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Already up-to-date!
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Trying simple merge with 7c2851542517e5071a08c8170b8921bf1e02681e
Trying simple merge with e7da29419e447230a3fa434fadaf948e15c2c796
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
HEAD is now at 347425d Merge remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/svn/trunk' into trunk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Push SmartGit sends commits that are reachable from refs/heads/trunk by "first parent" path until a commit with git-svn-id signature is met. Usually this commit has "refs/remotes/svn/trunk" reference.

According to the screenshot (AFAIU) commits reachable by "first parent" path lie on the blue line, but "svn/trunk" reference is on the pink line. This means that "trunk" commit parents are confused. So do the following

1. Undo the last merge commit.
2. Make sure that trunk lies on the pink line, otherwise move "trunk" reference to svn/trunk using "Reset..." command.
3. Make sure there're no external changes (run Pull+rebase option)
4. Merge "blue" branch again.
5. Push

Comment: I solved it by undoing all 6 commits on the blue line, cause they were cherry-picked changes from the green anyway. Then I only had two lines, like before and I could reset the local git-"trunk" reference to the "svn/trunk".